# Export SQL result to CSV but retain the newline values in fields

Tags: mysql, csv, export-to-csv, sequelpro

I am trying to export a query result into CSV via Sequel Pro and I want to retain its newline values.

I tried escaping using `REPLACE()` and I also tried using other terminators such as `;`.

My content looks like this

```
The word "adore" means to love something deeply. Other words that mean the same as adore are 
"cherish, treasure, love dearly"
```

How can I export this data into CSV retaining the newline?

*Please note that there is a `whitespace` character after the word **are** followed by a newline.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I remember correctly, you can choose to use comma as delimiter, enclose a whole string content with " at the front and the end of string, escape the " with "" in your string, and that way you can retain your new line content.

For example, instead of:

```
The word "adore" means to love something deeply. Other words that mean the same as adore are 
"cherish, treasure, love dearly"
```

Try changing above to:

```
other_content_in_csv,"The word ""adore"" means to love something deeply. Other words that mean the same as adore are 
""cherish, treasure, love dearly"" ",other_content_in_csv
```